# Not able to SSH into google compute engine server from developer console

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

I have a linux machine on google compute engine.I am not able to SSH into instance from developer console. I added SHH keys, still I cant access it through WinSCP. I was able to access it few days back. What is the problem and how can I solve it ? It is showing following message.

[image]

Comment: Is there anything relevant in the console logs?

Comment: I clicked on "Serial Console output" from developer console but no relevant logs found